# IOS 11 hide search bar

Tags: ios11, searchbar

When I try to hide the search bar in IOS 11 with

searchBar.ishidden = true

the search bar is hidden but the cell that contained the search bar remains as an empty cell.  How can I hide the search Bar and the cell containing the search bar?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about iOS, but does this help?

```
self.navigationItem.searchController?.isActive = false
let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.navigationItem.searchController = search
self.navigationItem.searchController = nil
```